# SSRS report extra page

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I have modified a sales invoice report of Dynamics AX. When I deploy and open report in Ax it shows that report has 1 page, but if I export it as PDF or if I print it out then it has two page, first page as it should be and second extra page only with header / footer. I tried to reduce size of header / footer but the problem isn't solved and also if I reduce them fields are moved from wanted positioned as we use pre-printed papers to print reports.

How can I get rid off extra unwanted page?

Comment: It could also be whitespace around the contents of the report.  if you (tepmporarily) add  boarders to your report contents  (tablix/rectangles/whatever), you can often see the culprit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Often I find that problems like this are related to the page size, report size, and margins. Take a look at the Report properties and take note of the page size and margins. Make sure that in the Body properties of your report, the size is less than the difference between the page size and margins.